# PHP - Create Associative Array From .txt File

Tags: php, arrays

I have .txt file formatted as such:

```
    "id","dealer_id","vin","stockno",
    "1","2","3","4",
    "5","6","7","8",
    "9","10","11",12"
```

My goal is push this into an associative array like such:

```
    "id"=>"1", "dealer_id"=>"2", "vin"=>"3", "stockno"=>"4"
```

My question is, the data loops through for every 4 entries. In the example above, I should have 3 arrays created like such:

```
    "id"=>"1", "dealer_id"=>"2", "vin"=>"3", "stockno"=>"4"
    "id"=>"5", "dealer_id"=>"6", "vin"=>"7", "stockno"=>"8"
    "id"=>"9", "dealer_id"=>"10", "vin"=>"11", "stockno"=>"12"
```

How can I make this happen within PHP -- if possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```php
<?php
$file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
$headers = fgetcsv($file);
$result = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
        if (!$row[0]) continue;
        $nextItem = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
                $nextItem[$headers[$i]] = $row[$i];
        }
        $result[] = $nextItem;
}
fclose($file);
var_dump($result);
```

This uses `fgetcsv` to read each delimited row of the file.  The first row is used as the header names.  Then, for each other row, we create a new entry and match the indexes to the header names.  I set it to 4 because you have a trailing delimiter that creates an empty entry at the end, if you removed those from the input you could use the length of `$headers` for the inner loop.

Here is the result of the `var_dump` for your data:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dealer_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["vin"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["stockno"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["dealer_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["vin"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["stockno"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["dealer_id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["vin"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["stockno"]=>
    string(3) "12""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's possible.

use http://www.php.net and read about the following functions

- file_get_contents()
- explode()
- str_replace()

I'll provide a short example:

```
$file = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
$parts = str_replace('"', '', explode(',',$file);
```

And then do a foreach-loop or something to add the key-value pairs in your array.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$getFileContents    = file_get_contents("demo.txt");
$explodeBr          = explode("\n", str_replace('"',"",$getFileContents));
$assocKeyStr        = array_filter(explode(",", trim($explodeBr[0])));
$otherDetails       = array_slice($explodeBr, 1, count($explodeBr));
$resultingArr       = array();
foreach($otherDetails as $indDetailStr) {
    $expDetail      = array_filter(explode(",", trim($indDetailStr)));
    $resultingArr[] = array_combine($assocKeyStr, $expDetail);
}
print_r($resultingArr);
```

Terms used:

1. `file_get_contents` which reads the file, within the server.
2. `explode` forms an array by dividing the given input needle, here in your case `\n` and `,`
3. `array_filter` to callback, if no callback passed, by default this returns not null associative values.
4. `array_slice` to create another array with limited and required number of arrays.
5. `count` to get the length of array.
6. `array_combine` expects two parameters with equal length arrays, first parameter array are the keys, second parameter to form values.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely it's possible - i.e. [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) returns you all lines from file, [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will let you iterate through lines, then you can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php),  [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to build desired structure.

Comment: would be nice if downvoter could explain why downvoting